# How do you declare a function interface without exposing Function properties

Tags: typescript

For example, I'm writing a type declaration file for my javascript library containing:

```
interface test {
  (): void
  x: number
  y: number
}
```

I want only the following to be exposed:

- test()
- test.x
- test.y

But the properties inherited from Function are also exposed:

- test.caller
- test.name
- test.length
- test.prototype

This clutters the suggestions provided by my IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript does not support operator-overloads like C++ does, so you can't overload the `()` operator to create a functor-type object in JavaScript or TypeScript, consequently any value that supports the `()` operator *must* be a JavaScript Function object, which means it inherits the `caller`, `name`, `length` and `prototype` properties. There is no way around this.

> This clutters the suggestions provided by my IDE.

This is not a good reason to try to subvert your language system. You should file a feature-request with your IDE vendor (or submit a patch if it's open-source) to hide or deemphasize inherited members.

Comment: Excellent explanation. Thanks